# GeoWebCache with fullWMS return zero-length responses

Tags: geowebcache

I'm trying to put GeoWebCache between our GIS and an imagery provider; serving WMS.

This works perfectly well when the client is an OpenLayers-based web application sending WMS requests which are essentially tiled, or at least snapped to "known" zoom levels.

The desktop GIS OTOH can take on arbitrary scales, and sends "classic" (non-tiled) WMS requests.

With fullWMS set to true in the configuration, "non-tile-conformant" (but perfectly legitimate requests) no longer fail - they simply return with zero-length content and status 200.

Without fullWMS, GeoWebCache returns errors of the form:

400: X,Y values for the tile index were calculated to be {64606.695394593364, 24520.52547640224} which had to be rounded to {64607, 24521} and exceeds the threshold of 10%. Perhaps the client is using the wrong origin?  ... which is what I understand to be correct when it's defaulting to WMS-C request handling.

With fullWMS set to true, the same or similar request comes back with nothing comes back at all:

Request URL:
https://xxxxxxxx/zzzzz_cache/geowebcache/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.1.1&layers=zzzzzz&styles=&format=image/jpeg&width=1024&height=1024&bbox=19466795.46371564,-5046051.28735157,19467101.21100286,-5045745.53848274&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=FALSE
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
xxx.yyy.zzz.www
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Cache-Control:
no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Cache-Control:
no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
0
...